# Macports does not install man pages

Tags: gcc, macports

I'm running `OSX Mavericks` and have installed `Macports`. I installed `gcc` via `Macports` which is working fine. However when I type `man gcc` I only get:

```
No manual entry for gcc
```

I was told I need to add the following to my `.bash_profile`

```
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
```

which I have done with no effect. Does Macports actually install the corresponding man pages? The man page for the 'port' command works fine as well as other preinstalled tools like clang.

Any help? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

What the man command looking for is the file 'gcc.1.gz' instead.
You may simply create the symbolic link under the folder `/opt/local/share/man/man1`

```
sudo ln -s g++-mp-4.8.1.gz gcc.1.gz
```

I also did the same for `g++.1.gz` and `c++.1.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem.

I'm not sure how macports sets the manpath or how to correctly change it in os x for that matter.

But if you do `man --path` you can see what the path is set to. On mine I see `/opt/local/share/man` is first.

If I then look for a gcc man page with `find` it shows me that there is in fact a man page in there

```
$ find /opt/local/share/man -name "*gcc*" 
/opt/local/share/man/man1/gcc-mp-4.8.1.gz
```

So then I tried `man gcc-mp-4.8.1` but that also didn't work.

In the end, it works if you just put the full path when calling `man`.

This works:

```
man /opt/local/share/man/man1/g++-mp-4.8.1.gz
```

Kind of crappy to have to put in the whole path but at least you can see it if you need to.

Comment: This seems to be a known bug https://trac.macports.org/ticket/29752 - but at least the man /opt/local/share/man/man1/gcc-mp-6.1.gz trick still works - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Putting `export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH` in your `.bash_profile` is correct, but it will only take effect on new terminals.